# Does C# SqlBulkTools#BulkInsertOrUpdate have a where clause?

Tags: c#, sqlbulktools

I've looked at the readme including all the notes and can't find a reference so I am erring on the side of 'it doesn't exist'.

I have a situation where I have a bunch of records that I want to merge into the server database from a local database these records may have been updated elsewhere so don't update that record e.g.

```
server.updatedAt > local.updatedAt
```

At the moment I'm using the #BulkInsertOrUpdate method which is overwriting everything. Is there any way to filter which records are saved?

```
result += new BulkOperations()
    .Setup<TABLENAME>()
    .ForCollection(records)
    .WithTable("TABLENAME")
    .AddAllColumns()
    .CustomColumnMapping(a => a.UpdatedAt, "updatedAt")
    .CustomColumnMapping(a => a.CreatedAt, "createdAt")
    .CustomColumnMapping(a => a.Deleted, "deleted")
    .CustomColumnMapping(a => a.Id, "id")
    .BulkInsertOrUpdate()                                
    .MatchTargetOn(x => x.Id)
    //.Where("UpdatedAt", (x,y) => y < x.UpdatedAt) // something like this
    .Commit(conn);
```

Comment: Bulk Copy only does inserts, not merges or updates. There is simply no functionality for that in the base TDS protocol. You can bulk insert into a temp table then merge from there

Comment: Check [EFCore.BulkExtensions](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions), I'm the author.